# Convexity of ($x^{1/4}+y^{1/4}+z^{1/4})^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I´m asked to determine if this function is convex, concave or neither.
($x^{1/4}+y^{1/4}+z^{1/4})^3$ for $x>0$, $y>0, z> 0$

The inside function is a sum of concave functions so is concave, the outside function is $x^3$ which is convex for $x>0$ and is increasing too.

With this in mind, can I conclude that is not either convex or concave? Or there is a relationship for that situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can conclude that $f$ is convex. Define $g :\mathbb R_{++}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R_{++}$ as the function $(x,y,z) \mapsto x^{1/4} +y^{1/4}+z^{1/4}$ and $h: \mathbb R_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ as the function $x \mapsto x^3$. ($\mathbb R_{++}^k$ denotes the vector with all positive entries.)

Then as shown in Boyd and Vanderberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), in Section 3.2.4 of Chapter 3, but the summary of the argument is as follows:

Application of the chain rule (twice) shows that

$$\nabla f (v) = \nabla g (v) \nabla h(g(v))$$

$$ \Rightarrow \nabla^2 f(v) = h''(g(v)) \big(\nabla g (v)\big)^T \nabla g(v) + h'(g(v)) \nabla^2 g(v) $$

Now recall that a twice differentiable function is convex on its domain if and only if the second derivative is positive semidefinite on the entire domain. The fact that $h$ is nondecreasing and convex means $h'' > 0$ and $h' > 0$.

From the above we can conclude $\nabla^2 f$ is positive semidefinite on the domain we defined it on because it is the sum of positive scalings of the positive semidefinite matrices $\nabla g(v)^T \nabla g(v)$ and $\nabla^2 g(v)$, where the former is psd by definition, and the latter is posiitve semidefinite since $g$ is convex because of how we defined it.